# ¿Es óptimo guardar el DBContext en sesión?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Para hacer mis consultas a la base de datos utilizo `Entity Framework` con `LinQ` a través de un `DBContext`.
Hace poco vi una aplicación que utilizaba las sesiones para guardar el contexto (`DBContext`).

Quisiera saber si eso es óptimo y si trae algún tipo de problemas.

**Inicializar el DBContext**

```
public static class Cat_caracteristica_variantesDataProvider
{
    const string dataContextKey = "DXCat_caracteristica_variantesDataContext";

    public static ProductoContext DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items[dataContextKey] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items[dataContextKey] = new ProductoContext();
            return (ProductoContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[dataContextKey];
        }
    }
```

**Métodos de consulta**

```
public static IEnumerable listar()
    {
        return DB.Cat_caracteristica_variantes.OrderBy(it => it.des_caracteristica_variante).ToList();
    }

    public static Cat_caracteristica_variantes obtener(short cod_caracteristica_variante)
    {
        return DB.Cat_caracteristica_variantes.Where(it => it.cod_caracteristica_variante == cod_caracteristica_variante).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Es un tema amplio por abarcar, sin embargo, me parece que puede llegar a ser óptimo en caso de que los patrones de diseño se llegasen a implementar de forma adecuada debido a que estarías utilizando un tema conocido **`DbContext per Request`**.  Básicamente estás alargando la vida de cada clase y así mismo el contexto, como decía, es un tema amplio del cual yo también me estoy informando. Me gustaría escribir una respuesta concreta pero no tengo los elementos necesarios, en cuanto tenga el tema más claro con gusto lo podremos debatir :)

Comment: @OP: Creo que hay una pequeña confusión. El código en tu pregunta guarda el `DbContext` en una estructura compartida para un "request" nada más, no una sesión.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces lo que hace el código es guardar el contexto en el request y supongo que optimiza las consultas a ese DataProvider ya que, como dice @Flxtr , alargo la vida del contexto hasta que dure el request. Es as?

Comment: No tanto optimizar las consultas, esto se haría directamente en el modelo de datos y/o base de datos, básicamente estás utilizando un `DBContext` a lo largo de lo que dure tu sesión, de esta forma no estás **creando contexto-disponer contexto-creando contexto-disponer contexto** ¿me explico? es un tema amplio que obviamente tiene sus pros y sus contras, por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa si la conexión se interrumpe y el contexto queda abierto? Todo este tipo de excepciones son las que se tienen que manejar a detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de muchas cosas, pero yo personalmente no lo haría, de hecho, si lo haces así, estarias cerrando la posibilidad e implementar diferentes patrones como repository o unit of work.

Por otro lado, si tu aplicación va a estar en Azure y esperas poder hacer escalamiento horizontal, dudo que el manejo de session se sincronize entre instancias, por lo tanto vas a tener que buscar hospedar tu session en una cache distribuida como REDIS o algo por el estilo.

Por último, la idea del DbContext como framework de acceso a datos desconectado es que las conecciones tengan el menor tiempo de vida posible y que tu puedas estar seguro de que la coneccion se va a cerrar una vez no la necesites, eso te garantiza la mayor escalabilidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.